# How to loop all children in hierarchicaldata?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3

I have arraycollection, in which root task contains children, children contains sub-children and so on.

For eg:

[0] root1

```
   child1
       child2
           child3
                data
```

[1] root1

```
   child1
       child2
           child3
                child4
                   data
```

How can I loop this using any loops

Thank u all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use recursion

```
loopChildren(root1)

function loopChildren(parent:Array):void {

    for(var i:String in parent){
        if(parent[i] is Array) loopChildren(parent[i]);
        else {
            //read data
        }
    }
}
```